# Dynamic link causes logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a .Net Core 2.1 application using stock Identity model for user login. One (MVC) page has a list of links that are generated dynamically based on user selections. The problem is that with a fresh browser session (newly opened incognito window), as soon as the user clicks one of those dynamically created links they are taken back to the login screen. After logging back in, all works normally. The user can click those links and doesn't have to log in again. The additional complication is that this only occurs when the project is published to a test server, not in development. I've tried refreshing the user identity cookie on arrival at the page in question. I confirmed that this worked, but it did not solve the issue. It seems to be related to the antiforgery cookie, but so far, all my efforts have failed.

In the view, a links such as the following work fine:

```
<a asp-action="action" asp-controller="controller">link 1</a>
```

However, using JavaScript to dynamically introduce a link does cause the mysterious logout issue as described:

```
<div id="test2"></div>

...

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test2").html("<a href='/controller/action/'>link 2</a>");
  });
</script>
```

I know there are many ways to create dynamic links like this and I have tried several routes, but this simplified version replicates my issue.

Thanks in advance for any insight into this problem.

Comment: "The problem is that with a fresh browser session (newly opened incognito window), as soon as the user clicks one of those dynamically created links they are taken back to the login screen." I'm confused. They wouldn't be logged in a new incognito window. That's kind of the point; it doesn't persist or carry over any of the cookies (otherwise, it wouldn't be "incognito").

Comment: can you specify which server are you using? as you mention it works in your local machine and not in the server, so probably the issue is there.
is the issue only in incognito window in the server or also in the normal mode?

Comment: 2 clarifications. Yes, it only happens when starting with a fresh browser session. The users logs in, then gets to this view and gets this mysterious logout the first time they try one of the links. To replicate the problem I have to close the browser completely down and start a fresh incognito window login again and go to the page with the links.  As for the server - IIS.

Comment: Also - it doesn't matter if I use incognito or otherwise on the dev server. I haven't been able to replicate the issue there. The test server also does this in a normal browser window on the first login of the day or after a computer restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the source of my issue, and I discovered that a critical detail was missing from my original question. I'm posting this as an answer in case anyone else runs into this same problem and so I have enough space to expand on my explanation. My dev and test environments have different paths to the web application. For that reason, I had written a JavaScript function to get the base url before appending the controller and action path. In my question I had simplified my script to:

```
$("#test2").html("<a href='/controller/action/'>link 2</a>");
```

In reality is was more like:

```
$("#test2").html("<a href='" + GetBaseUrl() + "controller/action/'>link 2</a>");

function GetBaseUrl() {
    return "//" + window.location.host + "/";
}
```

It turns out this little function was the culprit. I still don't understand why it caused the problem (and I'm not a JavaScript guru, so there is probably a better way to do this), but it was definitely the problem.

For anyone else having this issue, if the script is in the page or view, use:

```
$("#test2").html("<a href='@Url.Action("action", "controller")'>link 2</a>");
```

If you're trying to do this from a linked script use a relative path, which will depend on where your site.js lives, but in my case:

```
$("#test2").html("<a href='../../controller/action/'>link 2</a>");
```

Thanks.